# ASP.NET Identity. Register UserManager with Autofac

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, autofac

I have a webapi project where I use `Autofac` for dependency injection. The problem is that I can't figure out how to register UserManager class. It's throwing the error `"{The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context.} System.InvalidOperationException"`.

Please help.

In AutofacConfig.Configure():

```
 builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>().As<IApplicationDbContext>().InstancePerRequest()
 builder.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerRequest();
 builder.RegisterType<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().InstancePerRequest();
```

And that's how I use it:

```
    public class UsersRepository : IUsersRepository<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public IApplicationDbContext DbInstance { get; }
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private IUserStore<ApplicationUser> _userStore;

        public UsersRepository(IApplicationDbContext dbInstance, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore)
        {
            DbInstance = dbInstance;
            _userManager = userManager;
            _userStore = userStore;
        }

        public void Create(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            _userManager.Create(user);
            DbInstance.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

IUsersRepository:

```
public interface IUsersRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IApplicationDbContext DbInstance { get; }

    void Create(T model);
    void Update(string id, T model);
    void Delete(string id);
    List<T> GetAll();
    T Get(string id);
}
```

I tried this solution: https://gist.github.com/danielok/9271691 but then I have another error when making first call to users webapi controller `"ApplicationDbContext is not registered."`

Message:

```
    The requested service 'ToDoApp_Data.DbContext.ApplicationDbContext' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide 
the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
```

Stack Trace:

```
       at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context)
   at ToDoApp_Api.App_Start.AutofacConfig.<>c.<RegisterOthers>b__4_1(ParameterInfo pi, IComponentContext ctx) in D:\Dev\ToDoApp_Backend\ToDoApp_Api\App_Start\AutofacConfig.cs:line 58
   at Autofac.Core.ResolvedParameter.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CanSupplyValue>b__0()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
```

P.S. I think will useful to tell that I have other webapi controllers that I managed to make them work with autofac, but considering that before using DI it was instantiated as follow: UserManager _userManager = new UserManager(new UserStore(new ApplicationDbContext())); . I don't know how to register it.

Comment: it looks like some of your component have dependency on `ApplicationDbContext` and not `IApplicationDbContext`. Could you edit your post and include the stack trace of the error related to *`ApplicationDbContext` is not registered *?

Comment: @CyrilDurand , sure, I added stack trace.

Comment: the stack trace provided doesn't show which component is being activated. Do you have more information ? I guess it is `UserStore` could you check if that type is having dependency on `IApplicationDbContext` and not `ApplicationDbContext` ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand , I added some more info, that's all I have.